# Click button automatically more than once jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

When I click on a button I want to auto click it for example `4` times again after the click. So basically you fire it `5` times. I have a code like this to retrieve the number it should be clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var clickedTimes; 

    $( "form" ).change(function() {
     clickedTimes = jQuery('input#cfwc-title-field').val();
    });

    $('#single_add_to_cart_button').on('click', function(event){
        if ((clickedTimes-1)==0) {
                return;
        }
        clickedTimes -=1;
        console.log(`Click-Event triggered ${(5-(clickedTimes))} times.`);
        $( "#single_add_to_cart_button" ).trigger( "click" );
    });
});
```

For example the `clickedTimes = 5`

After clicking the add to cart button beneath it it should auto fire `4` times again on it because I fired it once myself.

Comment: Your code doesn't have a click event. Does your form `change` event fire on button click...? In any event, the answer is probably just to initialize a `for` loop of *`n`* size that fires the event inside of it.

Comment: Firstly, the code in the question seems unrelated to what you're asking. Secondly, this is a very odd requirement, but it would make more sense to put the logic under the `click` event in to its own function and just call that N times instead of faking multiple events which can lead to other issues. Better still, put the logic in a function which you call once and then loop N times. Perhaps if you could tell us why you feel the need to do this we can offer better alternatives.

Comment: You fired it once? So clicking the button triggers the "onchange" event in the form?
Then just do $("form").trigger('change') in a for loop. Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Edited my question, so the trigger should be in a loop for 5 times in this question. How can it be done?

Comment: You must be sure that what changed is really the form-field cfwc-title-field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution:

```
// clickedTimes=5; the value of clickedTimes must be set. 
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $('#single_add_to_cart_button').on('click', function(event){
        if ((clickedTimes-1)==0) {
                //clickedTimes=5;  .
                return;
        }
        clickedTimes -=1;
        console.log(`Click-Event triggered ${(5-(clickedTimes))} times.`);
        $( "#single_add_to_cart_button" ).trigger( "click" );
    });
})
```

Here is a working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Meziano/gyd65crp/)

Comment: The clickedTimes is filled everywhere now with a fixed number. How can it be dynamically filled?

Comment: Just declare it as a global var, than set its value where you want. Remove the 2 lines where I set its value to 5.

Comment: Do you get it? If you still have a problem let me know: try to provide more code to show where the value for "clickedTimes" come from and I will try to help you.

Comment: Still doesn't 100% get it. In my function `clickedTimes` = `aantal_tickets`. I get that value after changing the form field and put this number in `aantal_tickets`

Comment: In this case just set the value for the global variable in the function that handles the change-event of the from-field.
If you have more than one form field and you need to have different values for their respective clickedTimes you have to use an arry or a dictionary in this case.

Comment: In fact you need just one global variable clickedTimes. Just set it as I said in the function that handles the cahne-event of the respective form-field. If you have more than one form-field add them a css-class (for example 'ff'), and  add a function to handle the change event for form-filed having that css-class like so: $('.ff').on('change', function(event) {
   clickedTimes=event.target.text()});

Comment: I must see your HTML to answer, but it seems OK.

Comment: If it works smoothly don't forget to accept my answer please. If not let me help you.

Comment: Take a llok at the Fiddle: I have added  form-fields and it works as you want.

Comment: Can you tell me where is the script where you added the 2 Events-Handlers? I can't find it.

Comment: It is in my functions.php file of WordPress

Comment: Sorry, I can't see it. Try to describe your problem exactly, so I can understand it.

Comment: Think this is a other problem. Thanks for helping because my question is answered !!

Answer (score 0):

Try this This worked for me in similiar condition .

```
 var aantal_tickets = 4;   //Here put the number of times you want auto submit
      (function submit(){
        if(aantal_tickets == 0) return;
        form.submit();   //action you want to perform
        aantal_tickets--;
        setTimeout(submit, 1000);   //Each second
      })();
```

Comment: why go to all the trouble of encapsulating your code and then use a global variable? Also `form.submit();` will reload the page, killing your javascript so this would ultimately just fire once.

Comment: i have mentioned a comment beside form.submit as the action you want to perform. instead of form.submit using console.log(`Click-Event triggered ${(5-(aantal_tickets))} times.`);  may be helpful